# MvcSitemap provider with web.sitemap

Tags: provider, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a sitemap, which I use for Telerik treeview rendering, I would like to use the same sitemap for Mvcsitemap provider bread crumbs functionality. Since the sitemap nodes are different for both these, I would like to manipulate the mvcsitemap provider xsd so that I do not have to maintain two site maps (one for telerik and one for mvcsitemap provider). I tried tweaking the xsd and my bread crumb does not work.. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Telerik renders its views from a sitemapprovider - not directly from the sitemap, so you can just point Telerik to the MvcSiteMapProvider.